# Silverlight DataGrid column bind to object dont refresh

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have bound DataGrid to IEnumerable< Object >. Object has EntityCollection< Access > property and it is name Accesses. Then in  I put this

```
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn
                 Binding="{Binding Path=Accesses, Converter={StaticResource AccessesToTextConverter}}"
                 Header="Access"/>
```

All work fine. But when I add Access object to Accesses in my viewmodel DataGrid does nor refresh. Why? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding items to a IEnumerable collection which the datagrid will not do anything with. Your collection you bind to must implement INotifyCollectionChanged for the datagrid to automatically update.

If you are using a collection which holds your RIA services results as a property in an object collection that gets assigned as your ItemsSource, make sure you hookup the CollectionChanged event to the PropertyChanged event of your object like so:

```
    public EntityCollection accesses;
    public EntityCollection Accesses
    {
        get { return accesses; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Accesses");
            value.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { OnPropertyChanged("Accesses"); };
            accesses = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added object directly to Accesses collection. and it has INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: Thx. I am using Ria Services. I think put all collection to another is not good in my situation.

Comment: Your right, you should be able to assign the datagrid directly to the exposed property from RIA. Are you doing this? Or are you assigning an enumeration of objects that contain the RIA objects. Make sure the Accesses property is notifying when it's collection gets changed as a property change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify TwoWay for the mode in order to update the UI from the code for one thing:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn                 
    Binding="{Binding Path=Accesses, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource AccessesToTextConverter}}"  Header="Access"/>
```

Comment: Sorry - I confused the column binding for the DataGrid binding. Does the ItemsSource binding on the DataGrid have Mode=TwoWay?